# Regarding Bash and WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

so yesterday (August 2nd, 2016) Microsoft released their Anniversary Update which brought, among other things, a fully fledged bash shell to Windows. Here's what I am wondering, when we use the command prompt in bash mode, can I create/update a .bash_profile as I would on a Mac and have those changes be system wide? Or, do I still have to use the advanced system settings whenever I need to set a variable like JAVA_HOME.

I tried to google it, but seeing as this is only a 1 day old update it is expected that there is no answer. As an aside, I was directed to ask this question here in stead of in stackoverflow.com

Comment: it is my understanding that the win10 dev tools are not a windows version of BASH, but BASH itself, from the Ubuntu repositories, so as such, I expect it to have the same expectations of the environment that it would have on a Linux native system. Since you are pioneering, have you trie it?>

Comment: Not yet as I already have set up a JAVA_HOME, and calling vim ~/.bash_profile returns an empty one. I will look into it and update this question in the future when I have to set up a new environment variable.